# images being duplicated when navigating between pages in redux / react application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-redux, contentful

I am creating a react / redux application for learning purposes. I am attempting to pull the images from contentful through their api. I have set up an action, reducer and component which displays the image fine, but when navigating between pages the images are duplicated. Everytime I return to the same page the image is duplicated + 1 so if I visit the page five times the image will exist 5 times on that page.

It would be great if anyone could give me some pointers in how to debug this or even a solution to the issue.

*action*

```
export function fetchAsset(id) {
  const request = axios.get(`${API_BASE_URL}/spaces/${API_SPACE_ID}/assets/${id}?access_token=${API_TOKEN}`);
  return {
    type: FETCH_ASSET,
    payload: request
  };
}
```

*reducer*

```
import { FETCH_ASSET } from '../actions/index';
const EMPTY_ARRAY = []

export default function(state = EMPTY_ARRAY, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
  case FETCH_ASSET:
    return [ ...state, action.payload.data];
  default:
    return state;
  }
}
```

*asset component*

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchAsset } from '../actions/index';
import styled, { css } from 'styled-components';


const RespImg = styled.img`
    width: 100%;
`


class Asset extends Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.fetchAsset(this.props.assetId)
  }
  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    return true;
  }

  renderAsset() {
    var assetArray = this.props.assets;

    console.log(assetArray + ' this.props')
    return assetArray.map((asset, index) => {
      if (asset.sys.id == this.props.assetId) {
        return (
          <RespImg src={asset.fields.file.url} alt={asset.fields.file.fileName} key={index}/>
        );
      }
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="asset">
        {this.renderAsset()}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    assets: state.assets
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchAsset })(Asset)
```

*Adding the component to the page*

```
<Asset assetId={work.fields.featuredImage.sys.id} assetKey={index} />
```

Comment: Try not using `key={index}` but `key={asset.fields.file.url}` instead (or a unique id if you have in the asset object).

Comment: Thank you that worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem here is that you fetch this image several times, that is why it is all good during the first render.

You keep your images in the array, and maybe you download the same asset, and add it to the array, even though it might exist there already. For such entities, the technique called [normalizing](https://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/NormalizingStateShape.html) can be used, so your state will look like:

```
state = {
   [id]: Asset
};
```

Using this technique, you can get needed asset by id (you have it probably from the URL parameter).
Arrays in reducers are usually used for collections – for example, if you want to fetch all your assets. You can normalize response, and keep entities by id in one reducer, and result of collection requests in another one – so you'll have an array with ids, and an object with all possible Assets.

---

One more thing – @Dyo recommended you to put something into `key`, like `id` or `url`, and it is a good advice. However, if you open your console, you'll probably see something about `elements with the same key`. Basically, react does not render elements with the same key, so probably, your array of the same entities was rendered, but react rendered only one – all others were discarded.

Comment: Thank you, yeah I think you are right. I will take a look and see if I can get this implemented.